Conda is using a channel after I removed it
I am trying to install flask using conda and I got the following error.
conda install flask
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
 - intel
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for channel intel <https://conda.anaconda.org/intel>

After doing some research it looks like the intel channel is having issues, so I decided to remove it from my conda config using conda config --remove channels intel.
I ran conda config --show-sources to verify that the channel is removed from my .condarc configuration file.
This was my output:
==> C:\Users\[Username]\.condarc <==
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

For some reason when I try running conda install flask I continue to get the error UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for channel intel <https://conda.anaconda.org/intel> because conda is still including the intel channel in my channels list.
I'm not sure what else I can do to remove the intel channel and get conda to stop using it.
As mentioned above I've tried removing the channel using the conda config. I also restarted my powershell instance and opened a new one which resulted in the same error. I restarted my computer as well. Last I tried conda clean --all with hopes that maybe the channel list was stored in the conda cache.

Don't know how to fix the underlying issue, possible workaround: conda config --set allow_non_channel_urls True should allow conda install to ignore unreachable channels, in your case intel

Thanks for your response. I ended up just reinstalling conda since my environment didn't have to many packages. When reinstalling I chose not to add the intel channel.

@FlyingTeller's answer worked for me. Or more exactly, I did
conda config --remove channels intel
conda config --set allow_non_channel_urls True
conda update conda -c https://software.repos.intel.com/python/conda/ --override-channels

and that seems to have done the trick

I got Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - Unable to retrieve repodata (response: 403) for https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch/repodata.jsdone Solving environment: failed, any suggestion? thanks.

Probably the first question is how many packages do you have. If just a few then deleting conda and starting again from scratch might be the simplest. What I do now is use conda activate/deactivate on environments and do absolutely everything else with pip. I've pretty much given up on anaconda, sorry.
