How can I remove conda intel channel now that intel has removed conda
Intel has apparently changed its support for conda and now we should point to https://software.repos.intel.com/python/conda and not to whatever "intel" pointed to previously.
So for example, the following works:
conda update anaconda -c https://software.repos.intel.com/python/conda/ --override-channels
Annoying, but fair enough, it is their repo. And I can then remove intel as a channel and add the new url so that conda config --show channels shows just the new intel url plus default.
But now if I try conda update conda then it has added back the non-existent channel intel and [worse] refuses to anything because that channel is not available.
How do I force conda to really forget the old intel channel?

Apparently this questions is a duplicate.  I will close mine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78761316/conda-is-using-a-channel-after-i-removed-it
